# After upgrading jqGrid from 4.4 to 4.5.4, why doesn't this filter description code work?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have the following behavior in jqGrid 4.4 where i show a filter description:

[image]

after upgrading to 4.5.4 it shows this:

[image]

as you can see, it shows *object Object* instead of "begins with".

Here is my code (which runs on loadComplete event) which is used to display this filter description:

```
arOps = ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge", "bw", "bn", "in", "ni", "ew", "en", "cn", "nc"];


    loadComplete: function (data) {

        var newCapture = "", filters, rules, rule, op, i, iOp,
                    postData = jQuery(gridSelector).jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData"),
                    isFiltering = jQuery(gridSelector).jqGrid("getGridParam", "search");

        if (isFiltering === true && typeof postData.filters !== "undefined") {
            filters = $.parseJSON(postData.filters);
            newCapture = "Filter: [";
            rules = filters.rules;
            for (i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
                rule = rules[i];
                op = rule.op;  // the code name of the operation
                iOp = $.inArray(op, arOps);
                if (iOp >= 0 && typeof $.jgrid.search.odata[iOp] !== "undefined") {
                    op = $.jgrid.search.odata[iOp];
                }
                newCapture += rule.field + " " + op + " '" + rule.data + "'";
                if (i + 1 !== rules.length) {
                    newCapture += ", ";
                }
            }
            newCapture += "]";
        }
        jQuery(gridSelector).jqGrid("setCaption", newCapture);
        fixPositionsOfFrozenDivs.call(this);

        if (gridprefs && gridprefs.filter) {
            for (var prop in gridprefs.filter) {
                $('#gs_' + prop).val(eval('gridprefs.filter.' + prop));
            }
            $(".ui-pg-selbox").val(gridprefs.rows);
            $(".ui-pg-input").val(gridprefs.page);
        }
        gridprefs = {};

        $(this).triggerHandler("jqGridLoadComplete", data);

    },
```

Comment: What is the __arOps__ variable?

Comment: I updated the question with arOps definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the `odata` object is changed and it's not a string anymore, so you have to change your code accordingly and read the property text.

Change you code from:

```
op = $.jgrid.search.odata[iOp];
```

to

```
op = $.jgrid.search.odata[iOp].text;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/z6VLg/